# Content Assist (Ctrl + Space) Is not working for testNG.xml file in eclipse

Tags: testng-eclipse, testng.xml

Content Assist (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>) is not working in  Eclipse IDE for testng.xml .

Eclipse Version: Photon Release (4.8.0)

Comment: Do you know if this was working for previous versions of eclipse? If yes, then it perhaps could be a bug with the eclipse version that you are using. If it never worked with previous versions of eclipse as well, then I think you could ask for this as a feature request. TestNG wouldn't have any role to play in this.

Comment: Earlier It was working but after reinstalling testng plugin it is not working in older versions as well as newer versions of Eclipse